# Question regarding inconsistency in Electrostatic energy

Tags: electrostatics

[image: A perplexing Inconsistency]

What's the difference between the formula of finding the energy of an electrostatic system when the energy is found using

1)W=$\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_i q_iV(r_i)$

& when it's found using

2)W=$\dfrac{ε_0}{2}\int E²dτ$

If equation 2 gives us the work required to make the point charge from scratch,why is the work required to make a point charge infinite ?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that it simply follows from the above calculation. You can also see it by considering a uniformly charged sphere which has finite energy. As you shrink its radius, you'll find that the energy diverges. Mathematically, you can use Griffith's calculation and simply replace the lower bound of the $r$ integral by $R$, the radius of the sphere, ($\vec E=0$ inside by Newton's shell theorem), to obtain:

$$
W_2 = \frac{q^2}{8\pi\epsilon_0 R} \xrightarrow{R\to 0}+\infty
$$

The formulas are actually closer than what you might expect. Let $V_i,\vec E_i$ the fields created by charge $i$, then:

$$
q_iV_j(r_i) =  q_jV_i(r_j)\\
 = \epsilon_0 \int \vec E_i\cdot \vec E_j d\tau
$$

So you can view $(1)$ as $(2)$ after taking out each divergent self-energy which are independent of the points' positions anyway, so don't contribute to the work when moving the charges:
$$
W_2 = \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\int E^2d\tau \\
W_1 = W_2-\sum_i\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\int E_i^2d\tau \tag{3}
$$
Technically, the previous expression is meaningless as you subtract an infinite quantity to another infinite quantity. You can make it rigorous by a careful limiting procedure. First assimilate the point charges as uniformly charged spheres of radii $R$, so that each term in $(3)$ is rendered finite. You can therefore calculate $W_1^{(R)}$, an you get:
$$
W_1^{(R)}\xrightarrow{R\to 0} W_1
$$
Note that the moment you take $R\to 0$ is crucial, if you do it before the difference, you get a nonsensical result as in $(3)$. This is an example of regularisation, and similar methods are used to deal with the analogous infinities popping out of quantum theories.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that formula 1) is the Coulomb potential energy of a set of point charges (finite), while 2) is electric part of the Poynting energy associated with specific region of space. The latter is derived and applicable only under the assumption that electric charge is not distributed too singularly (point charges are not allowed).

Equation 2) is not applicable to assembling point charges, such assembling is not known to ever happen, because it takes infinite energy to put two charges of the same sign into the same point of space.

Comment: So Eq 2) amounts to assembling charges in infinitesimal amounts (dq by dq ) and this has to be done over a space with definite surface area or volume , we can't assemble all the dq's to a single point ,is that what you're trying to say ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Eq 2 is meant for models with finite charge densities. If there are point particles, Eq 2. is not applicable, and we go back to Eq 1 or its generalizations, such as $\int \mathbf{E}_1\cdot \mathbf {E}_2 dV $.